# Troubles with d3.js + react.js and passing data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js

Hi i'm having troubles with my code and don't know what i'm doing wrong (i'm making my degree project from college, still newbie using react), the things is i have a component fetching multiples endpoint of my API,

this is the code from the component:

**Data.js :**

```
import React from 'react';

class Data extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        
        this.state = {
            actionData:[],
            questionData:[]
        };
    }
    async componentDidMount(){
        const url = "https://api-tesis-marco.herokuapp.com/api/v1/users";
        const url2 = "https://api-tesis-marco.herokuapp.com/api/v1/questiondata/siete-colores";
        const actionData = await fetch(url)
        .then(response => response.json());
        this.setState({actionData:actionData});
        const data = await fetch(url2)
        .then(response2 => response2.json());
        this.setState({questionData:data});
    }
    render(){
        return ( //here is where i'm having trouble
            <dashboard data = {this.state.questionData} /> 
        );
    }
}
export default Data;
```

i don't know how to pass the data from questionData to this component

**dashboard.js:**

```
import React , {Component} from 'react';
import Pie from '../../piechart';
import Data from '../Data/Data.js'

class Dashboard extends Component{
    render (){
        
        //here is where i want my data
        const data = Data; 

        return(
            <div className="dashboard container">
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col s12 m6">
                        <Pie data = {data} width={200} height={200} innerRadius={60} outerRadius={100}/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        );
    }
}

export default Dashboard;
```

i want to do this so i can use my data to create a D3.js pie chart

also heres the code of my piechart component

**piechart.js:**

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import * as d3 from "d3";

const Pie = props => {
  const ref = useRef(null);
  const createPie = d3
    .pie()
    .value(d => d.value)
    .sort(null);
  const createArc = d3
    .arc()
    .innerRadius(props.innerRadius)
    .outerRadius(props.outerRadius);
  const colors = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);
  const format = d3.format(".2f");

  useEffect(
    () => {
      const data = createPie(props.data);
      const group = d3.select(ref.current);
      const groupWithData = group.selectAll("g.arc").data(data);

      groupWithData.exit().remove();

      const groupWithUpdate = groupWithData
        .enter()
        .append("g")
        .attr("class", "arc");

      const path = groupWithUpdate
        .append("path")
        .merge(groupWithData.select("path.arc"));

      path
        .attr("class", "arc")
        .attr("d", createArc)
        .attr("fill", (d, i) => colors(i));

      const text = groupWithUpdate
        .append("text")
        .merge(groupWithData.select("text"));

      text
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .attr("alignment-baseline", "middle")
        .attr("transform", d => `translate(${createArc.centroid(d)})`)
        .style("fill", "white")
        .style("font-size", 10)
        .text(d => format(d.value));
    },
    [props.data]
  );

  return (
    <svg width={props.width} height={props.height}>
      <g
        ref={ref}
        transform={`translate(${props.outerRadius} ${props.outerRadius})`}
      />
    </svg>
  );
};

export default Pie;
```

here's my data from the requested API as well

**Data:**

```
[
  {
    "Respuesta": "A",
    "porcentaje": 7
  },
  {
    "Respuesta": "B",
    "porcentaje": 3
  },
  {
    "Respuesta": "C",
    "porcentaje": 3
  },
  {
    "Respuesta": "D",
    "porcentaje": 10
  },
  {
    "Respuesta": "No ha respondido",
    "porcentaje": 76
  }
]
```

i know there's a lot of tutorials out there, but i don't find any specific for my case, i want to know what i'm doing wrong so i can create 4 of the same pie chart with 4 different API urls

Answer (score 0):

In `render` method of your dashboard component use `this.pròps` in order to get passed `data` prop.

```
const { data } = this.props
```

Comment: well in some extent, i suppose it works, but now it gives me an error in the side of my pie chart, the error tell me that data is undefined (TypeError: data is undefined) it highlight some code in pie.js module in the node_modules folder, the next highlight is in my piechart component in the useeffect block "const data = createPie(props.data);" i don't understand why